# In three throws of a pair of dice ,the probability of throwing doublets not more than twice.

Tags: probability

This question is so confusing in many ways. First I tried to list the number of possibilities to get doublet, but should we arrange our numbers and make sure they aren't doublet

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What is the probability of "throwing a doublet" on a single throw of a pair of dice?  What is the probability of this three times in a row?

Answer (score 1):

P(doublets) = $\frac{6}{36}$. The probability of throwing doublets not more than twice in three throws is the probability of throwing doublets but not throwing three doublets. Therfore, as P(3 doublets) = $(\frac{6}{36})^3$ (each roll is mutually exclusive) and P(no doublets) = $(\frac{30}{36})^3$ , the answer to the question would be 1 - $(\frac{6}{36})^3$ - $(\frac{30}{36})^3$ = $\frac{5}{12}$.